# Importing flask module in jython jar

Tags: java, python, jar, flask, jython

This is my first attempt at working with jython, so here goes!

I've got a little Python app using Flask as my web framework, and I want to package it up into a jar.

I've followed the [jar method tutorial here](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts), and I've got my app components all set inside the jar. However when I attempt to execute my script inside the jar using this command:

```
java -jar folder/myapp.jar myapp.py runserver
```

I'm met with your typical Python import error:

```
File "folder/myapp.py", line 24, in <module>
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, request, session
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I'm assuming I need to somehow package up my modules inside the jar with the rest of my code, but I'm at a loss as to how. And advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add the `flask` module to the root of `myapp.jar`.  You can do this with the `jar` utility that comes with the JDK, or use the `<jar>` task in Ant.  I am sure Maven has a way to do the same thing, but I don't know Maven.

Something like this should get `flask` into the root of your *.jar file, assuming that `flask` is the path to your `flask` module:

```
$ jar uf folder/myapp.jar flask
```

I am currently using Ant, and that would look something like this if all you are doing is adding `flask`:

```
<target name="add-flask-module">
    <jar basedir="flask" destfile="folder/myapp.jar" update="true"/>
</target>
```

Comment: I was able to add the modules I need to the jar, but I don't think my app knows to look for them in there. Is there a path I need to update?

Comment: No, anything you add to the root of your jar should be importable by programs inside the jar without having to touch `sys.path`.

Comment: Almost there. I'm now getting a syntax error from my flask import. `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
  File "app.py", line 25, in <module>
    import flask
  File "__pyclasspath__/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "__pyclasspath__/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
  File "__pyclasspath__/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 67, in <module>
  File "__pyclasspath__/werkzeug/_internal.py", line 26
    _cookie_params = set((b'expires', b'path', b'comment',
                          ^
SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input ''expires''`

Comment: @solrrt, this is really a new question that you are asking, and we should not ask new questions in the comments.